# Has anyone here ever threaded the left end of a rear hub? (To add a left-side freewheel)

Tags: hub, drivetrain, freewheel

I have found endless opinions on mass-manufactured hubs that are either left-side-threaded or 'reversible' or etc. I am not seeking information or opinions on these.

I am also aware of the available aftermarket left-side freewheels, and though opinions on those would be welcome they are not directly related to this question.

I am seeking insights and/or technique advice for *adding* the threading needed to receive a left-side freewheel onto a steel hub that already has a right-side threaded freewheel but has a smooth left side (unthreaded, no coaster brake or brake disc mount).

Examples would be how you set up your jig to maintain linear alignment as you thread (if you did-  and if you freehanded it how did you do that), how you managed the odd shape of the hub in clamping it for the work (without marring/damaging it), is there a particular die carrier/handle you recommend, what stood out as a hiccup or obstacle is setting up, was the small roundover athe very end a problem for beginning the threads, etc etc. Tips on execution and methods.

People will insist on the 'why' here, I suppose -  I want to add a second, separate, driveline to the bike, and I do not want to 'double' the right-side freewheel due to layout needs. To reduce rolling resistance from the new driveline, it needs to have a freewheel.

Dimensions:

OAL, bearing cap to bearing cap - 149mm

Bearing cap diameter - 35mm for 1st 7.5mm, then 36mm for 7.5mm

Bearing cap end to spoke flange face - 15mm

~7mm on the 35mm dia. section is usable as threaded surface

It's a 'fat bike' rear hub.

[image: Hub]

Hope someone here has some advice. It's a tricky thing to attempt if you don't have a machine shop.

Comment: I'm not sure on the physics but would a freewheel on the left require a reverse threading to counter precession? This may require a machine shop.

Comment: Yes, a left-side freewheel will need to be the reverse thread of the threading on the right side. This is so the forces applied by a forward-driving chain 'tighten' the freewheel onto the hub. If you threaded a 'normal' freewheel bearing onto the left side, you'd probably unscrew it when you applied any real force!! (not to mention a 'normal' freewheel would be freewheeling in that orientation.)

Comment: @DWGKNZ I don't think precession is a concern with freewheels. The threads in a freewheel turn to directly transmit torque, and so they are threaded such that they tighten under load (whereas threads subject to the wiggling that causes precession are threaded opposite to the rotation). Of course freewheels have to be reverse threaded on the left side, because then pedaling would directly loosen them.

Comment: @Kaz except that the OP specifically says "I am also aware of the available aftermarket left-side freewheels... they are not directly related to this question". Sounds as though he's going to DIY something instead.

Comment: @Móż I think that's a typo in the question; of course a left-side freewheel is needed for this, and the next sentence acknowledges it: *"... advice for adding the threading needed to receive a left-side freewheel"*.  Perhaps OP might have meant *"I'm aware of the after-market left-side-threaded hubs"* (but I want to make my own anyway).

Comment: @Kaz from the comments to my answer, I think it's going to take a lot of effort to discover what the OP is doing, what they're willing to do, and how they want to be helped. I'm leaving my attempt in to help anyone else who wants to have a go, although I'd otherwise delete it since it doesn't answer the question and seems to have offended the OP.

Comment: I really thought my wording was clear about my desiring advice and input on the specific task of applying threads to the hub without having a full machine shop. With the high hope that such advice would come from people who have done it or something similar. -- Maybe tell me how I can better make that clear? I want to be a good questioner, but I guess I am not. --I will be using a purchased freewheel, but have not decided on which one yet. I will not be using the gear that comes on it, it will receive a larger gear via bolts (that larger gear is a 50-tooth gear formerly used as a pedal gear).

Comment: @Nixt. Might it not be easier to tap a bolt circle in the hub and just attach the big gear that way directly to the hub? What are you making, a motorized bike?  Only motorbikes have huge sprockets on the wheel, due to the engine RPM's actually having to be geared down.

Comment: Should I not be in "Bicycles"? There isn't a "Machinist" stack - maybe "Engineering"?

Comment: Sounds like a task for an engineering firm, not a something to try at home.

Comment: @Kaz Yes, adding electric assist to a heavy bike. But I'm not using a kit, a hub motor, or anything 'normal'/'store bought'. Custom designed carrier under the seat for motor and jackshaft transmission, output on left. I live in a *very* hilly place and 'normal' ebike stuff is either underpowered or illegal here. It's a case of "Nobody has solved this particular issue so I guess I have to." As far as the freewheel - I desperately want to freewheel there at the hub, and not further forward in the gear train. Just want to sort out best attack method for threading it without a lathe!!!!

Comment: @kaz: How about cutting gear teeth into a (cheap) brake rotor?  It would have a good hub connection already, and the rear disk brake is the least useful.   Need to add a rim brake to keep it legal too.

Comment: Also, since the problem is that a hub with a left thread is not available in the form factor you want, how about at least finding an aluminum version of the hub you have now.  Then at least you're not machining steel.

Comment: @Criggie But that costs big money and then I can't say "I did this." And it's FUN for me to find ways to do hard things without having to hand them over to someone else. Half the joy of my projects is in this part- solving the problems.

Comment: @Kaz 1) Added a pic. There's no rotor mount present. Smooth steel. 2) Buying a new hub is *possible* but I really want to use what I have. 3) Based on the right side freewheel being present, I think I'll find a left side one that will work for the diameter of the hub. Didn't see that as a problem? 4) No need to cut the gear from a rotor when a front gear I already have bolts right on.

Comment: I think its a fascinating project and find it interesting.  Please do keep this thread updated with how you're going and what's worked for you.

Comment: One issue that may be a big one, is how thick is the steel on that end of the hub, is there even enough material there to properly machine threads into it? Or will your threading cut all the way through that shell?

Comment: @111936 It is five years later - How did you get on with this project?  Feel free to add and accept your own answer showing what you did, and any useful comments about pitfalls and findings.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the hub you have now is likely to be very difficult. It sounds as though you don't even have disk rotor mounts on the hub, so there's not a lot of structure there for you to attach to. Rather than getting caught up with how to weld extra metal on so you can machine threads onto it, it might be easier just to machine up a hub from scratch. The actual solid part of the hub is not at all complex, and since you will need a lathe anyway it would probably be easier to work that way than get into welding onto a hub that's not designed for the extra stresses you want to apply.

If you don't have access to a lathe you're going to find this project quite difficult. At some point, probably quite early on, you're going to need either a lathe or a large, expensive pair of dies to cut freewheel threads (a taper and square pair, since you need to cut right up to to end of the surface). Possibly two pairs of dies, because you might end up wanting a locknut on your freewheel thread.

More commonly people bolt a fixed sprocket to the disk brake mounts and drive that chain via a freewheel. It's not quite as efficient as putting a freewheel on the rear hub, but much simpler.

Some "put a petrol motor on your bicycle" kits attach a sprocket directly to the spokes, but it would be hard to overstate my dislike of that method. It is hard on the spokes, and hard to fix the wheel when those spokes bend.

The other easy-ish approach would be to flip-flop hub and re-cut one side to take a left hand freewheel. I haven't ever played with those, so I can't help you work out what thread is used.

Comment: Thanks for the time, Moz, but I pretty clearly stated my question. I'm trying to find insight/info on the actual execution of this task.

Comment: I've shuffled the paragraphs to put the bit you care about first. Does that help?

Comment: 1) Yes, it will not be easy to do this. 2) The right side is the same construction as the left side, and the right side is threaded. Thus, the steel is thick and strong enough to take threads already. 3) I do not have a lathe, and while challenging I know that doing this without one is possible. As stated, this is really what I seek advice and input about. 4) Again, yes it isn't going to be easy. Got it. Still want to do it. 5) As for the rest, please re-read the first two paragraphs of my question. Not buying a hub. Also - there are no flipflop hubs for a fat bike rear that I have ever found.

Comment: In that case I don't understand your question. You have the tools, you know it can be done, you don't want contrary advice, you're asking for... reassurance?

Comment: Not reassurance, & dissuasion isn't needed, either. Want advice and info on how TO do it, not that I shouldn't. I've done all sorts of weird nonstandard modifications to things to varying levels of quality but I am by no measure a machinist or a bike mechanic. I'm just determined to do this well and am willing to go the long way around the block to be able to say "I did this myself."  Don't have the dies yet because I have not selected which freewheel yet.    I edited the question to better describe my needs.

Comment: "determined to do this well" and your other restrictions don't fit together to me. You want to attach a 12mm wide freewheel to a 7mm wide flange... you can't do that properly without making the flange bigger.

Comment: @Nixt I think if you're not a machinist, you kind of have to become one first to do this.  Have you created interior or exterior threads before in any material, of any size? This doesn't exactly seem like a "hello world" exercise.  I don't think you can do this without a lathe; you might be able to do this with a cobbed-together jig that isn't formally a lathe, but is *de facto* a lathe. The hub has to spin around its axis, while a tool cuts away the material to create a precise cylinder of the right diameter which can then be threaded.

Comment: @Móż The right side freewheel is fitted to the hub in exactly the same way as I want to do the left side. And yes, it does not fully thread onto the hub and expose threads past the freewheel - the freewheel is only just past halfway engaged on the hub. But it WORKS as the drive gear for the pedals. Works with a big fat man sitting on the bike and pedalling hard. So I don't see doing the left side in the same way as the right side as a problem.

Comment: @Kaz This isn't my first go at threading. Have done gads of it in standard applications. Pipe inside outside, sheet metal, steel/aluminum, etc. But never threaded a stepped cylinder, and never used dies that let me thread up to a shoulder. Not worried about pulling it off. Just want to explore what others may have learned from their experiences before I commit to a method. And I don't necessarily HAVE to rotate the hub, I could rotate the tooling.

Comment: I wouldn't assume the right and left side of the hub are the same.  I made that assumption with an XTR hub back in the day trying to swap the end cones around to make a rear disc brake spacing work on a front setup on an old Pugsley.  I destroyed that XTR hub, because the right and left sides were not the same.  I wish you better luck.

Comment: Both ends of the hub measure the same diameter by caliper.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this without machine tools would mean using a die. Left drive freewheels have left hand threads in 1.375x24 and M30x1, and M30 is too small here. Off the shelf dies exist for neither in left threading.

Comment: Thanks for the input re: getting the dies. Will now have to investigate. As to diameter of freewheels, this page has nominal 34mm I.D. left side freewheels that appear to be the same as what's on my bike's right side. http://www.electricscooterparts.com/freewheelclutches.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going about this in a "this is what I have already" way, which leads to expensive custom solutions.

Consider that a rotor is only 2mm thick, so either you have very few threads of engagement, OR you have to make rotor with a deeper base.  An off-the-shelf rotor won't work, and threads are not a part of this solution.

Once you make a new rotor there's a good change it ends up thicker than 2mm, which means bicycle calipers won't fit.  Do you fit a heavy motorbike caliper or make your own ?   A motorbike caliper won't actuate off a bicycle hydraulic lever, so you need motorbike brake lever for the rear wheel, which will look weird, and may not fit your bars.  And so on down the slippery slope.

Instead. get a rear wheel hub that has disk rotor mounts already.  This lets you use common stock rotors and caliper.

---

In your frame photo I can't see a caliper mounting point.  Either it is out of shot, or you don't have one and will have to engineer that too.

Your best answer is to buy the frame you need, with the features you want.

If that's not possible/affordable, then you'll need to

- Braze/weld caliper mounts to the frame, and add sufficient reinforcement that the frame does not fail due to new side-loads.  And prep/paint properly.
- Rebuild the wheel rim onto a disk rotor compatible hub
- Assemble and set up brake.

If you can't weld/braze, don't shortcut or bodge.  Brakes are important and need to be done right.

Also, don't touch the other brake until your new rear one is working perfectly.  A working brake is far more useful than a non-working brake.

Answer (score 0):

note for this solution you will need 2 identical sized hubs)

i had that problem with a project hub like the one in the photo its steel and 3 pieces its a pressfit hub

i resolved the issue by cutting a notch in a 2x4 large enough to accept the hub shaft then tapping on the inside of the hub (blank side down) with a metal rod and mallet (same way you tap out a bracket cup) and rotating the hub in place every 2 or 3 taps until the assy came apart i did the same to a identical donor hub dropping out the threaded hub cap crown then rebuilding the first hub with the donor crown again tapping and turning until set

note prior to dissasembly on both hubs i scratched a center line under a spoke hole on both the shaft and crown assy to keep offset alignment

also its a good idea to scratch a line around the whole shaft at the base of the crown so youll know how far to tap the donor crown back in place (if you have access to a cheap bench press all the better!)

yeah the cheap asian hubs have that going for them this trick only works on them enjoy
you can send beer if you like!  whoop didi hoop didi
poop didi scoop   xD

Comment: Even if it would be possibile to source such a hub with the lefthand thread needed for the purposes of this question, I'm pretty sure reassembling a hub body like that beats the purpose of having extra reliable transmission in the first place.

Comment: What is a threaded hub cap crown? What process are you describing? There’s something about the terminology that I can’t follow.

Answer (score -1):

Yes I have and still have my 24 inch schwinn with 2 kranks  and  2 chains and freewheel on both sides of my bike  it's a cool design I thought of when I was young racing bikes

Comment: Welcome to Bike Exchange. Could you expand your answer on what you did to be successful? What tools were needed? Things to be careful about, watch out for? Did you have a failure that you needed to resolve? The whole experience you had and can pass on is what this answer needs. Just saying you did it leaves us wondering how?  And the questioner was curious about the how just as much as if it was possible and had been done before.